# Wicd set up on centos

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos-6, wicd

I am having difficulties with wicd on start up on CentOS 6. When it starts up it complains that it cannot connect to the DBus and that the daemon has shut down. When I check the log file there is nothing in there that suggests any sort of error at all, I have it starting up on run levels 345. I don't understand what is going on here and nothing I have seen in other places has really helped, but maybe I'm missing something obvious. Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally from memory, but I believe it means the daemon is not running.  Therefore, the client cannot run.  I think there's an init script for it that needs to run.  I forget how I fixed it for myself, but that's my memory of what was wrong.

If use use `chkconfig` and look to see if wicd is starting:

```
chkconfig --list | egrep -i wicd
wicd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

That means you have to set it on at boot time (or manually start it every time, yuck).

This should do it:

```
sudo chkconfig wicd on
```

Then if you do chkconfig again, you'll see:

```
chkconfig --list | egrep -i wicd
wicd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Assuming you have driver(s) for your WiFi and nothing else is wrong, you should be all set.